# How can I subtract values of each column of my dataframe from all other columns?

Tags: r

I have a simple datafrme

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  col2 = c(4, 5, 6),
  col3 = c(7, 8, 9)
)
```

And I want to have a new dataframe that will contain the results of subtraction of each column from all others, one by one. I assume that will do the job

```
result_df <- data.frame()

# Subtract each column from all the other columns
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  column_diff <- apply(df[, -i], 2, function(x) df[, i] - x)
  result_df <- cbind(result_df, column_diff)
}
```

but what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `cbind()` you need to combine elements with the same number of columns. I think you could set up `result_df` like this:

```r
result_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol = 0))
```

Or it might be better to create a list of column-differences, then combine them:

```r
cdiff <- function(i) apply(df[, -i], 2, function(x) df[, i] - x)
newcols <- lapply(1:ncol(df), cdiff)
data.frame(newcols)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple

In the {tidyverse} this can be done with `purrr::map_dfc()` using a function similar to what you had:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6, col3 = 7:9)

seq_along(d) %>% map_dfc(.f = \(x){d[,x] - d[,-x]})

#>   col2...1 col3...2 col1...3 col3...4 col1...5 col2...6
#> 1       -3       -6        3       -3        6        3
#> 2       -3       -6        3       -3        6        3
#> 3       -3       -6        3       -3        6        3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Updated

`purrr::map_dfc()` was deprecated in {purrr} 1.0.0 so it would properly be done now using `map()` with `list_cbind()` which enables one to specify the `names_repair` argument to control the naming.

```r
seq_along(d) %>% 
  map(.f = \(x){d[,x] - d[,-x]}) %>% 
  list_cbind(name_repair = "minimal")
#>   col2 col3 col1 col3 col1 col2
#> 1   -3   -6    3   -3    6    3
#> 2   -3   -6    3   -3    6    3
#> 3   -3   -6    3   -3    6    3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Fancy

If you you want to get fancy and have the new columns reflect the calculation that produced them, you could use `dplyr::rename_with()`.

```r
seq_along(d) %>%
  map(.f = \(x) {
    d[, x] - d[,-x] %>% 
      rename_with(\(y) {paste0(names(d)[x], "-", y)})
    }) %>%
  list_cbind()
#>   col1-col2 col1-col3 col2-col1 col2-col3 col3-col1 col3-col2
#> 1        -3        -6         3        -3         6         3
#> 2        -3        -6         3        -3         6         3
#> 3        -3        -6         3        -3         6         3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer the solution by @Ben Bolker, here is a fun one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

cdiff <- function(x) {
  df %>%
    select(-{{x}}) %>%
    transmute(!!paste0("col", x, ".diff") := df[[x]] - .)
}

map_dfc(1:ncol(df), cdiff)


col1.diff.col2 col1.diff.col3 col2.diff.col1 col2.diff.col3 col3.diff.col1 col3.diff.col2
1             -3             -6              3             -3              6              3
2             -3             -6              3             -3              6              3
3             -3             -6              3             -3              6              3
```